# Laravel Eloquent - Sum of a column values for multiple records from related data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following models: User, Order, OrderPayment

whereby each user has many orders, and each order has many order payments.

The orderPayment model has the attribute "total_paid"

I would like to get the sum of the  user's total paid for all his orders.

eg:
user has 3 orders.

- the first order has the two following payment records: 5$ and 4$.
- the second order has one payment of 10$
- the third order has two payment records of 1$ and 4$

the total sum i want is 5 + 4+ 10+ 1+ 4 = 24$.

I have tried the following but it's not working at all :

```
$user->orders->orderpayment->sum('total_paid');
```

but i get this error

> Property [orderPayment] does not exist on this collection instance

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to sum values from the OrderPayment model, it is easier to start there. Try to write it like this:

```
OrderPayment::whereHas('order.user', function($query) use ($userId) {
    $query->whereId($userId);
})->sum('total_paid');
```

Make sure all the relations are defined well.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
$user->orders->orderpayment()->sum('total_paid');
```